# Python - how can i read in and read out so that other readers can read it for further pursing?

Tags: java, python, linux, bash

I have to run the Java application and read the syslog to trigger some other Python based events.

At the same time i also need to dump and store it in /var/tmp/log.log of all java outputs, but because the new Python event controller is added that `/var/tmp/log.log` i was not able to create. Any idea how can i still make it? . For example:  java | python >> java logs as >> log.log  for tail -f

BEFORE: (worked)

```
$ java -cp /var/tmp/Audio.jar Main.Boot >> /var/tmp/log.log &
$ tail -f /var/tmp/log.log
```

AFTER: (not working)

```
$ java -cp /var/tmp/Audio.jar Main.Boot | python -u /var/tmp/consumer.py &
$ tail -f ????? how can i have the java syslog still dumped as like my BEFORE ????
```

/var/tmp/consumer.py

```
import sys, time, os
while True:
  line = sys.stdin.readline()
  if line:
    sys.stdout.flush()
    if "wall:on" in line:
      os.system("/var/tmp/me.sh")
  else:
    time.sleep(1)
```

/var/tmp/me.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0.0 
ps aux | grep "/var/tmp/pp.py" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9;
# System maintain..
python /var/tmp/pp.py &
sleep 3
ps aux | grep "/var/tmp/pp.py" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

```
$ java -cp /var/tmp/Audio.jar Main.Boot | tee /var/tmp/log.log | python -u /var/tmp/consumer.py &
$ tail -f /var/tmp/log.log
```

I would also do the awk/grep stuff inside python instead of going through a subprocess.

Comment: But how do i "append" using `echo "hello" | tee /var/tmp/log.log | xargs echo ;` ? (its only writing the last output right?)

Comment: try "tee -a /var/temp/log.log", which appends to the output.